# Open Source Alternative to ASP.NET Commercial Uber-Grids

Tags: asp.net, open-source, grid

The company I work for uses an ASP.NET grid component from a commercial vendor, but won't upgrade the buggy old version we have to a newer version because of cost.  Are there open-source alternatives to these Uber-Grids that we could take advantage of?

I'm specifically looking for hierarchical drill-down capabilities. I know there are some Javascript library plugins (stuff for jquery UI, etc) that could be used, but I would prefer a server-side control given the current coding conventions at my employer (server-side controls whenever possible, javascript when nothing else will work :-P )

Comment: The server-side first coding convention sounds backwards, at least from a performance standpoint.  I guess that's a side issue here though, and likely out of your control.

Comment: Yes, it's not a policy I agree with, but something I feel that I need to respect from the standpoint of other developers maintaining my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid Wrapper Control using ExtJS http://www.codeplex.com/ExtJsExtenderControl

Check out the [DEMO page](http://extendersamples.rodiniz.com/#) for the grouping feature, not sure how many levels you can go in though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this opensource project that extends ASP.NET GridView : http://johnsobrepena.blogspot.com/2010/01/coolgridview-new-release-resizable.html

1. Fixed column header, footer and
   pager
2. Scrollable content
3. User-resizeable column widths (new!)
4. Maintains scroll position and column
   widths after a postback or callback
   (new!)